# Does Killzone: Shadow Fall support gyro controls?

Tags: ps4, killzone-shadow-fall

I've read some comments online claiming that gyro controls were implemented in 2013's 'Killzone: Shadow Fall' (completely unreliable sources, no sense in sharing). I'm playing the PS4 version on PS5, there's no related setting in the control options and I can't get  in-game response by moving the controller.

'Killzone: Mercenary' (2013) on PS Vita has gyro support for making fine adjustments when aiming down sights. The PS3 Killzone games appear to also support motion controls in some form.

Comment: Doesn't appear on this list (it seems there isn't any comprehensive catalogue): https://reddit.com/r/PS5/comments/svbqnd/updated_playstation_list_of_games_with_gyro_aim/